# Link of class failed, apache poi

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache, apache-poi

I have been googling for this problem for hours, but I still can't find the solution.

here is the log error

http://i62.tinypic.com/w1s7z4.png (can't upload image directly)

and this is the code

```
public void getBaris() throws IOException
{
    InputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileUri));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FILE FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FILE NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

    workbook.close(); // just to make sure the workbook work, but it doesn't
}
```

Thank you..

Note : I already add poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar to add archieve jar in my project files and still got this error

Comment: Are you sure that you have [all of the Apache POI components and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on your classpath at *both* compile time *and* runtime? (Only it looks like you haven't....)

Comment: You should write that up as an answer, explaining what you had to do to fix it with the help of that page, so future people with the same problem can easily find the solution!